# How i can import my database dump file in mysql in ubuntu server

Tags: mysql

i am executing query for importing sql dump in ubuntu

```
 mysql -u username - p passsword databasenme < var/www/sql.sql;
error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u
```

Comment: exit first if you have login in mysql  from your terminal. fire your command from your home. hit exit command first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should not be any blank space between -p and the password.

```
mysql -u username -p<PASSWORD HERE> databasenme < var/www/sql.sql;
```

**UPDATE:**

I assumed you weren't logged in to mysql already. If you are, you should exit from mysql console and then retry.

Answer (score 3):

You can import .sql file using :

```
mysql -u <user> -p<password> <dbname> < mysqlfile.sql
```

**Note: There shouldn't space between `-p` and `<password>`**

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html

Time taken for importing huge files most importantly it takes more time is because default setting of mysql is `"autocommit = true",` you must set that off before importing your file.

First open MySQL:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Then, You just need to do following :

```
mysql>use your_db

mysql>SET autocommit=0 ; source the_sql_file.sql ; COMMIT ;
```

Comment: i have relogged to database and use my database but when i fire query it give same error

Comment: If you set a password for your user, you have to add -p parameter, regardless if you specify it on command line or in virtual mode. mysql -u yourUserName -poptionallyYourPassword_no_space_here_if_you_specify_one -h localhostOrWhatever yourDatabaseName < b3.sql

Answer (score 2):

You are logged in to mysql. press ctl+z to exit and try again.

Answer (score 1):

don't write user's password on this line, type only flag -p , and in new line enter password:

```
$ mysql -u user -p database_name < your_file.sql
Enter password:
```

EDIT:

Check .sql file for syntax, maybe have a syntax error in the file.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Comment: @Raj, can you show .sql file, i think you have a syntax error in the file.
Check file for syntax

Comment: @Raj, Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question as "has an accepted answer". 
p.s It is necessary for those who are faced with the same problem.